# Benefit of doing real analysis to understanding earlier topics.

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning, education

I am not in the senior year of high school yet, and I am self-learning real analysis using Terrence Tao's book (with knowledge in calculus), and have only skimmed through the year 12 (=senior year) syllabus.

I was wondering if doing real analysis now would benefit my understanding of the topics (probably sketching functions, transformations, proofs, geometric proof etc) when it comes to then. (Note: I'm not doing real analysis for this reason, but I am just curious as to the benefits).

Comment: not an answer i guess, but: u shud understand that stuff first

Comment: I see what you mean, but I find that a brief understanding of it is enough.